# Image not displaying from const when given value

Tags: javascript, html

My intention is to have one row with two columns, and have "quotes.img" image display in the first column, but I can't get it to display in my "imgbox" div.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <center>Column 1
      <div class="image" id="imgbox" img src="quote.img"></div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
      <div class="image">
        Column 2
      </div>
  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    const quotes = [{
      img: "https://i.imgur.com/wauvv4p.png"
    }];
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables aren't expanded in HTML, you need to do it in the JavaScript.

Also, since the object is in an array you need to index it. And you left out the `<img>` element in your HTML (it was mixed in with a `div`).

```js
const quotes = [{
  img: "https://i.imgur.com/wauvv4p.png"
}];
document.querySelector("#imgbox img").src = quotes[0].img;
```

```html
<div id="imgbox">
<img>
</div>
```